Why can't I use traits and modules that I see should be available in docs.rs?
I am writing a Modbus TCP server using tokio-modbus. When I try to access some traits and functions of the crate I get errors:
use tokio_modbus::server::tcp::{accept_tcp_connection, Server};

[dependencies]
tokio-modbus = "0.11.0"

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `server` in `tokio_modbus`
  --> src/server.rs:1:19
   |
1  | use tokio_modbus::server::tcp::{accept_tcp_connection, Server};
   |                   ^^^^^^ could not find `server` in `tokio_modbus`
   |
note: found an item that was configured out
  --> /home/<USER>/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-modbus-0.11.0/src/lib.rs:50:9
   |
50 | pub mod server;
   |         ^^^^^^
   = note: the item is gated behind the `server` feature

I have checked docs.rs and these do exist. I am not sure why VS Code isn't picking it up.

As stated by the error message, you need to enable the server feature of tokio-modbus. Put this in your Cargo.toml:
tokio-modbus = { version = "0.11.0", features = ["server"] }


Thanks,
Adding the server feature has the changed the error to
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tokio_modbus::server::tcp`
 --> src/server/server.rs:6:13
  |
6 |     server::tcp::{accept_tcp_connection, Server},
  |             ^^^ could not find `tcp` in `server`


@ArnavGupta https://docs.rs/tokio-modbus/0.11.0/tokio_modbus/#cargo-features you also need the tcp-server feature.
